# Parameter issue in SSRS 2005

Tags: parameters, reportingservices-2005

I've created a report in SSRS 2005 which returns 17 pages of data for one parameter, within this report there is a subreport, for 3 of these reports the data is not showing and I get the following message on the report.

> Error: Subreport could not be shown

And the output from the debug in Visual Studio is

> [rsErrorExecutingSubreport] An error occurred while executing the
>   subreport ‘subreport1’: One or more parameters required to run the
>   report have not been specified.

I've also included a text box in the subreport to check to see if the parameter is getting passed just to make sure it's not a data issue. For the ones I don't get an error the parameter is getting passed ok to the subreport.

If I run the subreport for the ones that are missing data is returned as expected.

Unfortunately, all this is within Visual Studio at the moment as I'm still waiting for the Report Server to be created, although I'm not sure how much of an issue this is so I'm unable to deploy to see if it's a Visual Studio issue.

Thanks in advance for any help.

Colin

Answer (score 0):

Just to give an update in case anyone else has the same issue, I found the following workaround which has enabled me to move forward for the time being until my reportserver is created, this works in Development Studio 2005 and 2008.

[SSRS Solution/workaround](http://prashantsingh11.wordpress.com/2012/11/09/ssrs-error-one-or-more-parameters-were-not-specified-for-the-subreport/)

Essentially the way around it was to create a table on the main report, delete the columns and rows that aren't needed and then drag the subreport into the table, set the parameters linking the subreport and main report and it should work. I've tested it in 2005 and 2008.

Regards

Colin